# Commulative degree distribution of nodes in a scale-free network

Tags: estimation, random-graphs

In a Barabasi-Albert model, which is a special kind of scale-free graphs, the degree distribution of each node is

$$P(k) \sim k^{-3}$$

Given $\| V \|$ (number of nodes), how can I compute "number of nodes whose degree distribution is less than or equal to $k$ (cumulative distribution)"?

Note that the concern here is "~"! I am not sure, but I think in order to compute the degree distribution and its cumulative, I should turn "$\sim$" into "=" (How?)

Of course I can generate some graphs and make use of sampling to estimate the exact degree distribution, but is there a way to mathematically estimate it?

Comment: I didn't understand the "number of nodes whose degree distribution is less than or equal to k (cumulative distribution)" I think the word distribution shouldn't be there.

$P(k)$ is the probability of some vertex has degree exactly $k$.

I think you want to know the CDF of the random variable $N_k = \text{number of nodes with degree} \le k$, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The exact degree distribution $d(k)$ for a scale free network constructed using the Barabási-Albert model is given by:

$$
d(k)=\frac{2m(m+1)}{k(k+1)(k+2)}
$$

Where $m$ is the number of nodes added in each step. This formula can be derived through the use of the master equation as explained in this [paper](http://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.63.062101). Furthermore the complementary cumulative degree distribution can be calculated as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\overline D(k) =& \sum_{i=k}^{\infty} d(i) = \sum_{i=k}^{\infty}\left[\frac{2m(m+1)}{i(i+1)(i+2)}\right]\\
=&m(m+1)\sum_{i=k}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{i}-\frac{2}{i+1}+\frac{1}{i+2}\right]\\
=&m(m+1)\left(\frac{2}{k}-\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\\
=&\frac{m(m+1)}{k(k+1)}
\end{align}
$$